# Google SignIn: Error 400. The requested URL was not found on this server. That's all we know

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I've implemented Google SignIn on my React Native app using react-native-firebase and react-native-google-signin.

It's working as it should on iOS Simulator on my MacBook. However, when I submitted to the AppStore, the Apple Review Team rejected it saying that the Google Login was showing the error as shown in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

I've been unable to reproduce this bug. It logs in perfectly fine on my device. Any idea on what's causing the issue on the Apple Review team's device?

Comment: what ended up being the issue? running into something similar

Comment: It was an issue with the network the phone was connected to. I requested the Apple Review Team to check their network. It may be a case where either the network is blocking access to Google's servers or Google's servers have blacklisted the IP in some way.
Switching the network fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a gmail id which is not registered with firebase console for this app.
Example: You are using abc@gmail.com to register this app in firebase console. So, this error appears.
Try to use any other gmail address like xyz@gmail.com, to avoid this error.